# Java Swing adding a JButton to a JFrame doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have been coding with Swing for a long moment in windows and when I switched to Manjaro Linux, something as basic as adding a `JButton` to a `JFrame` wouldn't work. (Also I have no output in the console, no missing libraries only a blank window).

Can someone help me figure this out?

Here is the code:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("My button");
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the code you've shown has no main method. But as @Chris states, please post code that runs and reproduces the problem for us. Please tell the details, how you run it, how you debug it (println's or use of a debugger).

Comment: I've copied your code, it is working for me.

Comment: *`window.setSize(600,600); window.setVisible(true); window.add(button);`* should be `window.add(button); window.pack(); window.setVisible(true);`. Always add all the components before setting the window visible. `window.setSize(600,600);` is no better than a guess, whereas `window.pack();` makes the window the size it needs to be.

Comment: No need to re-open the question -- you're calling `.setVisible(true)` ***before*** adding all components, and often this won't work since you're rendering the GUI before it is complete. This is also a duplicate of a gabillion other similar questions, which is why it shouldn't be re-opened. Solution: only make the JFrame visible *after* you've added all components and packed it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: see the above

Answer (score -1):

[image]

As mentioned in a comment:

```
window.setSize(600,600); 
window.setVisible(true); 
window.add(button);
```

Should instead be

```
window.add(button); 
window.pack(); 
window.setVisible(true);
```

Always add all the components before setting the window visible.

`window.setSize(600,600);` is no better than a guess, whereas `window.pack();` makes the window the size it needs to be.

This is the code used for the above screenshot. Further details in code comments.

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayButton {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("My button");
        // This is a random guess as to how big the window should be. DON'T GUESS
        //window.setSize(600,600);
        // The button should be added before the frame is packed to size and displayed
        window.add(button);
        // But since you want it BIG, let's make it so, 
        // usefully by first increasing the text size
        button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(60f));
        // Then add a chunk of insets - adjust to need.
        button.setMargin(new Insets(20, 100, 20, 100));
        // Make the window the size it NEEDS to be to display the button.
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```